# Geometry collinear/orthocentre & collinearity

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

The coordinates of A,B, and C are (0,1),(t,0), and (s,0) respectively. Show that the coordinates of the circumcentre O are (s+t)/2, (1+st)/2) and verify that O,G,H are collinear, where G is the centroid and H is the orthocentre.

I think my prof said we needed to use linear algebra to solve it.

Comment: There is a typo in your $x$-coordinate for $O$.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have coordinates for the centroid (which are easy)? Which geometric definitions of these centers do you know? How could you turn those into equations you can solve?

Comment: Note: There is a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/502069/35416) by the same poster asking about various coordinates in that same parametrized triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just used the slopes and found each intersecting line.